# Use JOOQ Multiset with custom RecordMapper - How to create Field<List<String>>?

Tags: jooq

Suppose I have two tables `USER_GROUP` and `USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE`. I have a classic relation where one userGroup can have multiple dataSources and one DataSource simply is a String.

Due to some reasons, I have a custom RecordMapper creating a Java UserGroup POJO. (Mainly compatibility with the other code in the codebase, always being explicit on whats happening). This mapper sometimes creates simply POJOs containing data only from the `USER_GROUP` table, sometimes also the left joined dataSources.

Currently, I am trying to write the Multiset query along with the custom record mapper. My query thus far looks like this:

```
List<UserGroup> = ctx
                .select(
                        asterisk(),
                        multiset(select(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE.DATASOURCE_ID)
                                .from(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE)
                                .where(USER_GROUP.ID.eq(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE.USER_GROUP_ID))
                        ).as("datasources").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::value1))
                )
                .from(USER_GROUP)
                .where(condition)
                .fetch(new UserGroupMapper()))
```

Now my question is: How to create the `UserGroupMapper`? I am stuck right here:

```
    public class UserGroupMapper implements RecordMapper<Record, UserGroup> {
        @Override
        public UserGroup map(Record rec) {
            UserGroup grp = new UserGroup(rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.ID),
                    rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.NAME),
                    rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.DESCRIPTION)
                    javaParseTags(USER_GROUP.TAGS)
            );

            // Convention: if we have an additional field "datasources", we assume it to be a list of dataSources to be filled in
            if (rec.indexOf("datasources") >= 0) {
                // How to make `rec.getValue` return my List<String>???? 
                List<String> dataSources = ?????
                grp.dataSources.addAll(dataSources);
            }
        }
```

My guess is to have something like `List<String> dataSources = rec.getValue(..)` where I pass in a `Field<List<String>>` but I have no clue how I could create such `Field<List<String>>` with something like `DSL.field()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to get a type safe reference to your field from your `RecordMapper`

There are mostly two ways to do this:

1. Keep a reference to your `multiset()` field definition somewhere, and reuse that. Keep in mind that [every jOOQ query is a dynamic SQL query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), so you can use this feature of jOOQ to assign arbitrary query fragments to local variables (or return them from methods), in order to improve code reuse
2. You can just raw type cast the value, and not care about type safety. It's always an option, evne if not the cleanest one.

#### How to improve your query

Unless you're re-using that `RecordMapper` several times for different types of queries, why not do use Java's type inference instead? The main reason why you're not getting type information in your output is because of your `asterisk()` usage. But what if you did this instead:

```java
List<UserGroup> = ctx
    .select(
        USER_GROUP, // Instead of asterisk()
        multiset(
            select(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE.DATASOURCE_ID)
            .from(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE)
            .where(USER_GROUP.ID.eq(USER_GROUP_DATASOURCE.USER_GROUP_ID))
        ).as("datasources").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Record1::value1))
    )
    .from(USER_GROUP)
    .where(condition)
    .fetch(r -> {
         UserGroupRecord ug = r.value1();
         List<String> list = r.value2(); // Type information available now

         // ...
    })
```

There are other ways than the above, which is using jOOQ 3.17+'s support for [`Table` as `SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/). E.g. in jOOQ 3.16+, you can use `row(USER_GROUP.fields())`.

The important part is that you avoid the `asterisk()` expression, which removes type safety. You could even convert the `USER_GROUP` to your `UserGroup` type using `USER_GROUP.convertFrom(r -> ...)` when you project it:

```java
List<UserGroup> = ctx
    .select(
        USER_GROUP.convertFrom(r -> ...),
        // ...
```

Comment: The above way with USER_GROUP instead of asterisk() doesn't work for me and yields compile errors. I am on jooq 3.16 at the moment. Is it also a JOOQ 3.17+ feature? I read your response more that only the below stuff should be JOOQ 3.17+ related. "no suitable method found for" ... method DSLContext.select(SelectFieldOrAsterisk...) is not applicable.....

Comment: @Theo: Yeah, it's a jOOQ 3.17 feature. I'll show the 3.16 way...